# Use Core Data's transient property as cache

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caching, core-data

I've got a *Core Data* model that I'd like to be presented using `UITableView`. The thing is that every `UITableViewCell` has its own custom height and it takes some time to calculate it. Therefore I'd like to pre-calculate and cache them.

Here's my idea:

Every model would have one transient property called `cache`. This property would contain my own cache objects (custom subclass of `NSObject`) that would be able to lazily calculate their data.

And here are my questions:

- Is it a good idea to use transient property for storing my `cache` objects? Or would it be better to store them in a `NSDictionary`? If so, would it be safe to use `ObjectID` as a key?
- Upon app's launch, I will need to run background pre-calculation for all `cache` objects. Would it be a good idea to access all the objects (possibly a few thousands) using `NSFetchRequest` and ask their `cache` object pre-calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Rudolf,

I solve this problem using a simple `@property CGSize` on my entity used in the table view. It checks to see if the size is zero when the row height is requested (`-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`) and, if so, calculates it, saves it in the ivar and returns it. It is quite straightforward and it doesn't need to be a property in the model. If this height could change, then you need to track those conditions and inform the table view anyway. Hence, you can blow away the cached value then.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

It seems the property you are trying to cache isn't very dynamic, since you are calculating it at the application's launch. You are better off making it a persistent property and calculate the value upon saving to the database. If, for some reason, the value change, you can re-calculate the value. This works even better if you are saving all new records on the entity on a background thread.